# Is it impossible to test code that calls the connectapi as a community user?

Tags: unit-test, community, connect-api

My test class currently includes the code from here only, with the exception described below: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Testing_with_RunAs

I've added this line of code just above the class: @IsTest(SeeAllData=true)

When I run this test I receive the below error:

> "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, You're creating a duplicate contact
>   record. We recommend selecting the "Contacts" tab, performing a search
>   for the existing record instead."

Removing the `(SeeAllData=true)` part makes the tests all pass.  The problem is that I need `SeeAllData` in there because I also need to add a bit of code to this class that will call a controller method which uses portions of the ConnectAPI that require `SeeAllData=true.`

So what's going on here?  Is it not possible to test code connecting calls to the `ConnectAPI` which require `SeeAllData=true`?

Comment: As an alternative you can use Test.istestrunning() method to skip some code execution during test run or use static boolean to skip some code .You can use two different methods and during each test run you can flip boolean .

Comment: That's one of the weird things here.  I tried surrounding the Contact creation code with a try/catch and simply swallowed the error,  Finally I did a select to get the created contact (the one that didn't throw the error, assuming my code was somehow running twice).  Turns out no contact was inserted!  What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

As per Salesforce documentation you need **seeAllData=True** when testing methods for ConnectAPI. We don't have much control for that.

However to solve your issue, you can attach timestamps to unique fields, while populating them. I use this as a best practice to duplicate errors.

This is what I will do to modify your code:

```
Account a;
Contact c;
System.runAs(userWithRole) {

    a = new Account(name = 'TEST ACCOUNT'+system.now());
    Database.insert(a);

    c = new Contact(AccountId = a.id, lastname = 'lastname'+system.now());
    Database.insert(c);

}
```

Comment: Trying this I receive the exact same error as I noted above.  I had previously tried something simliar in which I used some randomized text as the last name, thinking that somehow my code was being executed twice but that appears not to be the case.